# Warning: Failed to initialize WMA message routing support

Tags: java, java-me, wma

I am using Eclipse for Java ME development. I am getting this warning:

```
Warning: Failed to initialize WMA message routing support
```

Is there any problem with WKT? I am using WKT2.5.2.

Comment: sorry thats the quickest I could reply . hello.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your hosts file to update your computer name with your computer's current IP adress (in LAN) and the problem will resolve itself. You may also use `127.0.0.1` as your computer's IP.

If you're on Windows, hosts file is located at `%Windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

If you're on Linux, hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts`.